# reference objects on the stack

Tags: c#

Does C# allow you to put reference objects on the stack? Why would you want to do that? What does this mean?

Comment: I don't think C# has anything to do with `stack` or `heap` or anything else. It's more about `.Net Framework`

Comment: In terms of the C# language? This means nothing. There is no stack.

Comment: This is a homework question if I ever saw one.

Comment: Oh wait, it could mean: `var s = new Stack<object>(); s.Push(new object());`...

Comment: **This is a perfectly reasonable question and it should not have been closed**. C# allows you to force allocation of a set of *unmanaged value type* onto the stack via the unsafe stackalloc declaration (see section 18.8 of the specification for details); it is **perfectly reasonable** to ask whether C# also allows the same for reference types, and if not, why not.

Comment: The answer is no, there is no way in C# to force a value of reference type to be allocated on the stack. *The reference itself* will be allocated on the stack if the reference is in a local variable (or temporary) that is not a closed-over local of an anonymous function, and is not in an iterator block. (Though this is an implementation detail, not a guarantee.) Similarly, as an implementation detail a value type that is local and not closed over or in an iterator will also be allocated on the stack.

Comment: Note that it is in theory possible for an implementation of the CLI to determine that an instance of a reference type has short lifetime and therefore could allocate its memory out of the temporary stack pool rather than the long-lived heap. As a practical matter, to my knowledge it never does so.

Answer (score 4):

It's implementation-specific - it's up to the C# compiler to decide how to translate the source code into its target platform, and the C# spec doesn't guarantee how objects are allocated. Assuming an IL backend, it's then up to the execution engine to *really* decide how memory is allocated, within the bounds of the generated IL. (There are *some* clearer guarantees there, I believe, but I doubt that it prohibits future optimizations.)

The closest I know of anything like that is stack allocating arrays, which is only available in unsafe code, and I don't believe you can really get a normal reference to the array afterwards anyway.

As for why you'd want to do such a thing - presumably if you could guarantee that nothing but your current method was interested in an object, you'd like to make use of fast allocation and not bothering the GC...

Answer (score 0):

No, reference objects can only live on the heap (i. e. allocated via `new`).

In C++ you might want an object on the stack to avoid allocation/deallocation/reference tracking hassles. Unless the object is to be used outside of the current function, there's no reason to have it on the heap. In C#, given its garbage-collected nature, lifetime tracking is not a concern.

Answer (score -1):

Well the *reference* to your object is always on the stack. If you want the entire object to reside on the stack, you could define it as a **struct** instead of a **class**

As to why you would want to do that, if this is an object that used a lot, you might be able to increase performance by having the object reside in the stack instead of accessing the heap.

Comment: And this doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: "If you want the entire object to reside on the stack, you could define it as a struct instead of a class." Why do people try to perpetuate this myth? Let me fix that: "If you want the object to be treated with value semantics, make it a struct."

Comment: What if the reference is itself inside a class?  If you have class C { string s; } then where is the reference to the string stored, on the stack or the heap?  Suppose you have class C { int x; } -- is the int stored on the stack or the heap?